# Can't make draggable table in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am JS newbie, and I need to make my table draggable, I have this code 
in jquery which works exactly the way I want, but I need it in JS

$(document).ready(function(){
    var c = {};

```
$("#dragTable tr").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            c.tr = this;
            c.helper = ui.helper;
        }
});


$("#dropTable tr").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var drag = ui.draggable.text();
        $(this).find("input").val(drag);

        $(c.tr).remove();
        $(c.helper).remove();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: HI, welcome to SO. do you just want do get rid of Jquery as a dependency? or write a entire thing in vanila Javascript without using any libraries? which by the way is not a easy task.

Comment: Hi Lakshan, thank u. Let me show you what I had before:                         function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}   Which works fine if you are using divs as droppable and pics as draggable, but now I need to use tables, and my code no longer works.

Comment: give us a description about what are you tring to do here. And if you can add your code as a working code snippet,  It would be really helpful.

Comment: I have  2 tables populated dynamically. I just want to be able to drag randomly rows  from table 1 and drag it to table 2. And I want to do it in JS

Comment: got it.. can you edit your question with  js only code with your html?